# How to implement shadow (ambient light) background in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to implement shadows like the image below?

I try many ways as `CardView`, `elevation`, many `custom views`, `drawable`. But that was different from the wanted shadows.

## CardView

`elevation of CardView` is `ambient light` + `key light`. But, I want just `ambient light` elevation.

[image: shadow of CardView.]

## I Want this shadow.

[image: I want this shadow.]

Comment: have you tried using [**`CardView`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView)

Comment: if u find any solution then please share with us ....

Comment: did you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Starting with API 28 you can set the color of the shadows.

If you want the ambient shadow only, then you need to set the color of the key light(aka spot light) to transparent.

You can do so by adding the following to your view tag in xml:

```
android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Now only key/spot light will show.

and for ambient shadow

```
android:outlinesSpotShadowColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Also check

```
setOutlineAmbientShadowColor() and setOutlinePostShadowColor()
```

to do it programmatically

You can also set them to other colors if you don't want a black shadow.